# How to use special characters in a powerShellScript

Tags: powershell, batch-file, jenkins, variable-expansion

So I am trying to use the below script do dynamically put different values in a properties file
But powershell will not let me use special characters such as !

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

rem Set the properties file path
set "PROPERTIES_FILE=src\main\resources\config.properties"

rem Replace placeholders with Jenkins parameters in the properties file
powershell -Command "(Get-Content '%PROPERTIES_FILE%') | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace 'USERNAME=(.*)', 'USERNAME=%Username%' } | Set-Content '%PROPERTIES_FILE%'"
powershell -Command "(Get-Content '%PROPERTIES_FILE%') | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace 'PASSWORD=(.*)', ('PASSWORD=' + [regex]::escape('%Password%')) } | Set-Content '%PROPERTIES_FILE%'"


rem Optionally, print the updated file contents for verification
type "%PROPERTIES_FILE%"

rem Execute your Maven command
mvn clean test -Dtest=ScriptTest
```

I am trying to use Jenkins parameters to update a config.properties file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `enabledelayedexpansion` from your [`setlocal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/setlocal) statement.

- In other words: Replace line `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` with  just `setlocal`

`enabledelayedexpansion` is what "eats" the `!` characters - even those present in the *values* of statically referenced variables, such as `%Password%`.

`enabledelayedexpansion` is only needed if you no need *dynamic* variable expansion, by enclosing variable references in `!...!`, e.g. `!Password!`, as distinct from the *static, macro-like* expansion  that regular `%...%` variable references perform.

While the `enabledelayedexpansion` feature is sometimes necessary, e.g. for building up a variable's value *iteratively* in a [`for`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/for) `/f` statement, it is problematic for interpreting *any* `!` as being part of a dynamic variable reference in literal use and in `%...%` expansions, and *quietly removing it* if it isn't - unless explicit *escaping* is employed.

The following batch-file content demonstrates this problem:

```bash
@echo off & setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

:: This "!" will be "eaten"
echo [hi!]

echo --

:: In literal use, you can *escape* "!", using "^"
:: Note that - awkwardly - whether you need *one or two* "^" depends
:: on whether the argument is inside "..." or not.
echo [hi^^!]
echo "[hi^!]"

echo --

:: In %...% variable references, stand-alone "!" are also "eaten",
:: but via !...! they are preserved.

:: Due to `enabledelayedexpansion`, this assigns verbatim "hi!"
set "FOO=hi^!"

echo [%FOO%]
echo [!FOO!]
```

The above outputs the following, proving that stand-alone `!` is "eaten" (quietly removed) in both (unescaped) literal use and in `%...%` variable expansions:

```
[hi]
--
[hi!]
"[hi!]"
--
[hi]
[hi!]
```

Note:

- Variable references - both static and dynamic - permit a *substitution* (substring replacement) technique: e.g,
  `set FOO=BAR_NONE`, followed by `echo %FOO:_=-%` or `echo !FOO:_=-!` (with `enabledelayedexpansion` in effect) result in `BAR-NONE`.
- In principle, you can leverage this in `%...%` variable references too in order to inject the necessary *escaping* before *dynamic* interpretation due to `enabledelayedexpansion` kicks in - e.g., `echo [%FOO:!=^^!%]` or `echo "[%FOO:!=^!%]"` - but, just like with escaping the *literal* use of `!`, *needing to choose the number of `^` instances for escaping based on whether the reference is inside `"..."` or not* is awkward - and, fundamentally, choosing dynamic expansion via `!...!` avoids that problem.

Comment: So it should look like

@echo off

rem Set the properties file path
set "PROPERTIES_FILE=src\main\resources\config.properties"

Comment: @RazvanCalina: No, you still want `setlocal` so as not to affect the global session state. In other words: Replace line `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` with  just `setlocal` - I've updated the answer to make that clearer.

Comment: Thank you very much, I was at this for like 12h and could not get it to work, this is incredible!!!

Comment: @RazvanCalina: It won't affect the solution in your case, but please see my updated answer, which adds some nuance.